# Why is this $0=0.000...$ correct/incorrect?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

How can I prove that $0.000...$ is actually $0$ written in another way? Is something infinitesimally small actually zero? If $0.000...$ is infinitesimally small, is it countably infinite? Is zero countably infinite?

Edit: 0.000... is recurring

Comment: It's more usual to quibble about $0.999\cdots$ rather than $0.000\cdots$.

Comment: What else do you think the decimal expansion of $0$ might be, if it's not $0.000\dots?$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But $0.0000\ldots$  often comes up in such arguments since it's  $1-.999\ldots$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Although in those situations, the amateurs write $0.0\cdots01$.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A decimal expansion is an infinite series. Your series is $$ 0+\frac{0}{10}+\frac{0}{100}+\frac{0}{1000}\ldots =0.$$

So yes, it's zero. To carefully prove it's zero we use the fact that the limit of a series is the limit of the sequence of partial sums and the partial sums are all zero. To show that the limit of the sequence of all zeros is zero you only need use the definition of a limit.

As to the rest of your question, no, it's not infinitessimal, it's zero. There are number systems that have infinitesimal elements, but decimals like you wrote are almost universally considered to refer to a real number that is the limit of the series the decimal represents.

And no, it's not countably infinite. You are confusing the fact that there are a countably infinite number of terms in the series with the idea that the number itself is countably infinite. Zero is not countably infinite. Nor is any infinitessimal. Infinitessimal things are small. Countably infinite things are big (at least compared to finite things.)

Answer (score 1):

A correct notation for $0.000\ldots$ is $0.\overline{0}$. It is by definition the limit of the sequence 
$$(0,\ 0.0,\ 0.00,\ 0.000,\ldots)=(0,0,0,\ldots)$$ which is $0$.

- *Countably infinite* can  be a property of a set. It is not a property of a number.
- [*infinitesimally small* numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal) is a concept that also does not apply  here,

Answer (score 1):

$$0.0000000...=\\1-0.999999....\\$$
where we know $0.99999...\to 1 $
$$\bf{remark}:$$
$a=0.99999...\\10a=9.99999999... \\\to 10a-a=9.99999...-0.99999=9\\ 9a=9\\\to \\a=1$